# PostgreSQL point-in-time recovery

Tags: postgresql

In the case of MySQL, you can use the binary log file after the backup file to recover except for specific queries.

In the case of PostgreSQL, is there a way to recover without specific queries using archive files after backup files?
recovery.conf only has end point options.

```
ex)
backup_file --------delete---------current
         |________(skip query)__________|
                  archive files
```

Comment: PITR is a point **in time** recovery, not a "point in SQL script" recovery. And it's based on transactions, not individual statements. So no, you can no skip transactions at will when doing that. You will need to stop right before the first transaction you do not want to restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only goes to prove how fragile MySQL recovery is...

Different from MySQL, PostgreSQL does not log SQL-like information in the transaction log, so you cannot easily determine which statement caused which WAL entry. And even if you could, such "recovery" would leave the system in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It was very helpful.